# storing in collection and displaying in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, arraylist, collections

I have to make an assignment where there is a basic login page using servlet & jsp and where there is a signup page. Signup page redirects to another jsp wherethe information is filled and after submit it should shoe another page where there is information of all the previously registered members.
I donot have to use Database or file handling for data storage. I can only use collections for this.
How should I code this?

Comment: Looks like homework ... No problem with it, but you should show what you have already tried. Currently this question is too broad an in risk to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to make a data structure, keep it in the context/application. Use it in JSP or servlet whenever needed.
You can initialize it in a ServletContextListener (the good way) or if you want a quick solution then make the data structure public static in any class (the bad way).

Answer (score 0):

You can use property files for the data storage. You can save your login details and other required details in a property file, and load the file when the application is started. Validate the login credentials with the login data in the property file and redirect it to other page when success.

If you wish to use collections, then after loading the property file *(load-on-startup)* you can add the contents of the property file to a hashmap and use it.